# Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#session.removeAttribute('message') in thymeleaf"

Tags: spring-boot, session, thymeleaf

I am trying to remove my view like this from my html file:

```html
<div th:if="${session.message}" th:classappend="${session.message.type}" class="alert" role="alert">
    <p class = "text-center " th:text="${session.message.content}"></p>
    <th:block th:text="${#session.removeAttribute('message')}"></th:block>
</div>
```

But it throws error

```
Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "#session.removeAttribute('message')" (template: "signup" - line 19, col 43)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parseDocument(MarkupParser.java:393)
    at org.attoparser.MarkupParser.parse(MarkupParser.java:257)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:230)
    ... 48 more
```

Here is my controller code...

```java
    User addedUser = this.userRepository.save(user);
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    session.setAttribute("message", new Message("Successfully Register", "alert-success"));
    return "signup";
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
    session.setAttribute("message", new Message("Server Error !!" + e.getMessage(), "alert-danger"));
    return "signup";
}
```

Can anyone ans me how can I fix this issue...?

Trying to remove attribute from session but unable to do so...

Comment: Don't add it to the session in the first place. Just add it to the model. You shouldn't be programming logic into your views (only that related to the view not to state).

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your point...  Can you explain it a little bit more for me?

Comment: What isn't clear? Don't add it to the session use the model (like the user) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method is no longer used
you have to create a utility bean and create a session removing method then use that method in thymeleaf to remove the attribute

class:

```
    package com.Contact.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@Component
public class sessionUtilityBean {
    
    @Bean
     public void removeMessageFromSession() {
            try {
                System.out.println("removing message form session ");
                HttpSession session = ((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getSession();
                session.removeAttribute("message");
                
                
                
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            
            }

}
```

}

then use the method in the thymeleaf:

```
<div th:if="${session.message}"
                        th:classappend="${session.message.type}" class="alert "
                        role="alert">
                        <p th:text="${session.message.content}"></p>
                        <th:block
                            th:text="${@sessionUtilityBean.removeMessageFromSession()}"></th:block>
                    </div>
```